# Setting a pointer to a non-static member function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to setup a function pointer that is set during execution based on a set of user parameters. I would like to have the function pointer point to a non-static member function but I can't find how to do it.

The examples I've seen say this can only be done with static member function only or use global variables in straight C.

A simplified example follows:

```
    class CA
    {
    public:
        CA(void) {};
        ~CA(void) {};
        void setA(double x) {a = x; };
        void setB(double x) {b = x; };

        double getA(const double x) {return x*a; };
        double getB(const double x) {return x*b; };

        void print(double f(const double), double x) {
            char cTemp[256];
            sprintf_s(cTemp, "Value = %f", f(x));
            std::cout << cTemp;
        };

    private:
        double a, b;
    };
```

The implementation part is

```
CA cA;
cA.setA(1.0);
cA.setB(2.0);

double (*p)(const double);

if(true) {
    p = &cA.getA;  //'&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
} else {
    p = cA.getB;  //'CA::getB': function call missing argument list; use '&CA::getB' to create a pointer to member
                  //'=' : cannot convert from 'double (__thiscall CA::* )(const double)' to 'double (__cdecl *)(const double)'
}

cA.print(p, 3.0);
```

So how do I get p to point to either 'getA' or 'getB' so that it is still useable by 'print'.

From what I have seen, the suggestions are to use boost or std::bind but I've had no experience with either of these. I'm hoping that I don't need to dive into these and that I'm just missing something.

Compiler MSVC++ 2008

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't forget that a member function accepts an implicit `this` parameter: therefore, a member function accepting a `double` can't be the same thing as a non-member (free) function accepting a `double`.

```cpp
// OK for global functions
double (*p)(const double);

// OK for member functions
double (CA::*p)(const double);
```

Also, the way you *invoke* them is different. First of all, with member functions, you need an object to invoke them on (its address will eventually be bound to the `this` pointer in the function call). Second, you need to use the `.*` operator (or the `->*` operator if you are performing the call through a pointer):

```
p = &CA::getA;
CA cA;
(cA.*p)();
```

Consistently, you will have to change your definition of function `print()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void print(double (CA::*f)(const double), double x) 
{
    // Rather use the C++ I/O Library if you can...
    std::cout << "Value = " << (this->*f)(x);
};
```

So finally, this is how you should rewrite your `main()` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    CA cA;
    cA.setA(1.0);
    cA.setB(2.0);

    double (CA::*p)(const double);

    if (true)
    {
        p = &CA::getA;
    } 
    else {
        p = &CA::getB;
    }

    cA.print(p, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: Function `print` needs to change too, to receive proper function pointer.

Comment: So I'm confused on
p = &CA::getA;
Doesn't this mean that you're trying to access a static member function?

Comment: @PartTimeUser: No, it does not. It's the syntax for taking the address of a member function.

Comment: Groovy. In a lot of the examples I perused I was getting hung up on the 'p=&CA::getA' section. 
This works great but I'm still confused on the it. If I add

Comment: Groovy. In a lot of the examples I perused I was getting hung up on the 'p=&CA::getA' section. I read that as trying to access a static member function.
This works great.

Comment: I was very confused until I learned that non-static member functions are NOT copied to each instance of a class (huge memory waste!). Instead, all instances (even a billion of them) share a single non-static member function that is stored in the definition of the class, and that when we call `object.func()`, the compiler is passing `this` instance as an argument to the method `func` so that `func` knows which instance it is operating upon. I suppose the difference between static and non-static is whether or not `this` is ever passed to the single copy of the member function. Non CS-person here

Comment: `double (CA:*p)(const double);` needs to be `double (CA::*p)(const double);`

Answer (score 9):

### Compilation Issue

**This answer focuses on the compilation issue presented in the question.** I would not recommend implementing this as a solution.

Pointers to member functions are best dealt with with `typedef`s and a macro.

Here's the macro for calling a member function:

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))
```

**Source:** [[33.6] How can I avoid syntax errors when calling a member function using a pointer-to-member-function?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html), [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#typedef-for-ptr-to-memfn).

This saves you having to remember the ugly `(object).*(ptrToMember)` syntax any time you wish to call a member function by pointer.

In your `class`, declare a `typedef` called `CAGetter`, this will make variable declaration much simpler:

```
class CA
{
public:    
    typedef double (CA::*CAGetter)(const double x);
```

Then you can declare your `print()` function quite simply:

```
    void print(CAGetter f, double x)
```

The body is also simple, clear and concise:

```
    {
        std::cout << "value = " << CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this, f)(x) << '\n';
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
CA a;
a.setA(3.1);
a.setB(4.2);

// Using a variable...
CA::CAGetter p = &CA::getA;
a.print(p, 1);

// without a variable
a.print(&CA::getB, 1);

// Calling the functions from outside the class...
std::cout << "From outside (A): " << CALL_MEMBER_FN(a, p)(10) << std::endl;
std::cout << "From outside (B): " << CALL_MEMBER_FN(a, &CA::getB)(10) << std::endl;
```

### Design Issue

Passing a pointer to a member function into a method of an instance of the same class is a design smell (you wouldn't normally pass a member variable to a method, this is no different). There is not enough information in this question to address the underlying design issue but this problem could probably be solved with separate `print()` methods, a member variable or with inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Great explanation, but your code smell claim is equivalent to suggesting that one should never use their hands to point at their own body because they are part of the same individual unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use pointer to method:

```
class CA
{
    public:
        typedef double (CA::*getter)( double );
        CA(void) {};
        ~CA(void) {};
        void setA(double x) {a = x; };
        void setB(double x) {b = x; };

        double getA(const double x) {return x*a; };
        double getB(const double x) {return x*b; };

        void print(getter f, double x) {
            char cTemp[256];
            sprintf(cTemp, "Value = %f", (this->*f)(x));
            std::cout << cTemp;
        };

    private:
        double a, b;
};

int main()
{
    CA cA;
    cA.setA(1.0);
    cA.setB(2.0);

    CA::getter p;

    if(true) {
            p = &CA::getA;  
    } else {
            p = &CA::getB; 
    cA.print( p, 3.0 );
}
```

Or use boost::bind

```
class CA
{
    public:
        typedef boost::function<double( double )> getter;
        CA(void) {};
        ~CA(void) {};
        void setA(double x) {a = x; };
        void setB(double x) {b = x; };

        double getA(const double x) {return x*a; };
        double getB(const double x) {return x*b; };

        void print(getter f, double x) {
            char cTemp[256];
            sprintf(cTemp, "Value = %f", f(x));
            std::cout << cTemp;
        };

    private:
        double a, b;
};

int main()
{
    CA cA;
    cA.setA(1.0);
    cA.setB(2.0);

    CA::getter p;

    if(true) {
            p = boost::bind( &CA::getA, &cA, _1 );
    } else {
            p = boost::bind( &CA::getB, &cA, _1 );
    }
    cA.print( p, 3.0 );
}
```