# How can I pass function pointer of a non static member function in a static member function in another class

Tags: c++, static

```
class A{
static void callback(void(*fun)());

};


class B{
void f1();
}


int main{
B b;
A::callback(b.f1);
return 0'
}
```

following error I will get while compiling if  f1 is non-static member function

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from â <unresolved overloaded function type> â to â void (*)
```

How can I resolve the issue without making f1 as static

Please help me

Comment: It would be clearer if you showed a few lines of code demonstrating what you mean.

Comment: Feels like there is another question... Why would you care about that address?

Comment: There is no resolution to this issue without making *some* compromise, because what you are literally asking for is impossible. What compromise is appropraite for you depends on the context. Therefore if you want some help you've got to engage, describe what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a pointer to a non-static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035905/setting-a-pointer-to-a-non-static-member-function). Also see [Obtaining a function pointer to a non static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527325/) for a less dated solution using a lambda expression and `std::function` instead of a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> static method

All non-template member functions of a class have one address, regardless of the instance of the class they're accessed through.

What static class functions have special is that they don't get passed the `this` pointer, and so they can be called without a class instance, but through the class name itself (ie `class::fn`).